# java.lang.NullPointerException on clearAnimation()

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

How this crash is possible? It works 99% of the time and sometimes there is this crash...

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.clearAnimation()' on a null object reference
com.XXX.VerticalPagerFragment.onViewPagerTouchDown

private void onViewPagerTouchDown() {
        if (isAdded()) {
            mPageIndicatorLayout.clearAnimation(); <<< CRASH
            ...
        }
    }
```

Object `mPageIndicatorLayout` is mapped with butterknife:

```
@BindView(R2.id.page_indicator_layout)
    View mPageIndicatorLayout;
```

This above method is called from this viewpager listener:

```
@Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                    super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                    if (isAdded()) {
                        if (state != ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            onViewPagerTouchDown(); <<< HERE

                        } else {
                            onViewPagerTouchUp();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I can't absolutely understand how this crash can occur in this context? Have you got an ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Add crash stacktrace

Comment: What does the logcat say ?

Comment: May be it relates to fragment lifecycle, try to remove listener before view is destroyed.

Comment: Seems like mPageIndicatorLayout is getting null...try kotlin synthetics or findViewById

Comment: mPageIndicatorLayout.post{ mPageIndicatorLayout.clearAnimation()   }

Comment: My guess is that:
1. Your layout and pager are not in the right view hierarchy which can be causing the view to be never inflated
2. Make sure pager and the view are attached to the same parent `ViewGroup` 
3. Passing the view reference inside the call back it would be that you're leaking the view's reference intentionally, so I would be careful with that